# Difference between the ACCESS default buttons ADD NEW RECORD and SAVE RECORD

Tags: ms-access

I see that they work for the same purpose, both of them fill a record in a table, I can tell that the difference is that *Add New Record* put in blank all fields while *Save Record* does not. Am I right? Is that the hole difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An An *Add New Record* button moves the record pointer to the new record (at the end of the form or datasheet). If the current record was changed but not saved ("dirty"), Access must save the changes (or at least try to) on order to move the record pointer.

A *Save Record* button does not move the record pointer but save (or try to) the changes of the current record.

If in your scenario a "new record" gets saved with blank fields by clicking either button, there must be some background procedure that automatically fills a (maybe hidden) field in your form as soon as the record pointer arrives at the new record (thus making the record "dirty"). But this is not the default behaviour.